# Iniciar sesion en Api rest

Tags: php, json

buenas tardes, estoy realizando un script php que consulta los datos voip de un usuario de Textme.com

Ellos no proporcionan una documentacion api pero analizando su pagina encontre un json que imprime las credenciales voip, el detalle es que requiere tener la sesion iniciada para funcionar, yo tengo mis datos de conexion pero obviamente al hacer la consulta a json sin haber iniciado sesion antes me muestra un error de usuario no autorizado, la pregunta del millon de dolares es:

Como envio mis credenciales de inicio de sesion a Textme.com/login sin tener que ir a la pagina  realizar la consulta al json de mi usuario,

a continuacion les dejo el codigo que llevo hasta el momento el cual funciona siempre y cuando yo valla a iniciar sesion a la pagina antes si no, muestra error, no autorizado:

```
    //leer datos del json de Textme.com
    <?php 

    $datos =file_get_contents('https://www.textnow.com/api/users/NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO');

    #No le pasamos el parámetro TRUE porque podemos trabajarlo como JSON  
    $jsonObject = json_decode($datos);

    echo "\n\n------- Valores y claves -------\n\n";
    foreach ($jsonObject->sip as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k : $v\n";
    }

?>
```

Repito el codigo funciona si antes yo inicio sesion manualmente en la pagina pero me gustaria hacerlo de una forma mas dinamica, espero puedan ayudarme con esta gran duda, saludos!